Запись json в Excel библиотека Pandas
Есть функция которая записывает JSON данные в файл Excel:
import json
import pandas as pd


def Json_to_Excel(json_data):
    pd.read_json(json_data, convert_axes=True).to_excel('file_name.xlsx', index=False)


json_data = [{'DateForm': '2024-01-12'},
             {'GUID': '15f24792-3013-410b-97bd-cea4d08cf9c5'},
             {'ListType': '4'},
             {'Region': 'Такого тега нет в файле'},
             {'ObjectsType': '002001002000'},
             {'Categories': 'Такого тега нет в файле'}]

Json_to_Excel(json.dumps(json_data))

Вывод данных из функции Json_to_Excel() несколько неожиданный:
D:\Python\OKS16\OKS_16\OKS_16.py:149: FutureWarning: Passing literal json to 'read_json' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a literal string, wrap it in a 'StringIO' object.
  print(pd.read_json(json_data, convert_axes=True))
0  2024-01-12  ...                      NaN
1         NaN  ...                      NaN
2         NaN  ...                      NaN
3         NaN  ...                      NaN
4         NaN  ...                      NaN
5         NaN  ...  Такого тега нет в файле

[6 rows x 6 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0

Как можно исправить код, что бы данные записывались в одну строку без NaN

Значение, которое вы привели в переменной json_data в формате Python-списка (который содержит словари), а не в формате JSON

Поправил вопрос

в строке кода json.dumps(json_data) происходит сериализация JSON если проверить будет class 'str'

вероятно. вам нужно что-то такое:
from io import StringIO


def Json_to_Excel(json_data):
    df = pd.read_json(StringIO(json_data))
    df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
    # df.to_excel('file_name.xlsx', index=False)


Благодарю, за ответ. Что еще заметил, если при первоначальной сериализация JSON передать данные в кортеже а не в словаре [["DateForm", "2024-01-12"], ["GUID", "15f24792-3013-410b-97bd-cea4d08cf9c5"], ["ListType", "4"], ["Region", "\u0422\u0430\u043a\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0442\u0435\u0433\u0430 \u043d\u0435\u0442 \u0432 \u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b\u0435"], ["ObjectsType", "002001002000"], ["Categories", "\u0422\u0430\u043a\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0442\u0435\u0433\u0430 \u043d\u0435\u0442 \u0432 \u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b\u0435"]] тогда файл запишется корректно

по какой то причине pandas ожидает данные в кортеже

не "по какой-то", а по вполне понятной - pandas расценивает словарь как серию - ключ - колонка, значение(я) - значения. если вас список серий, то pandas пытается его нормализовать, ожидая, что в каждой серии будут схожие колонки. и каждую новую серию записывает за новым индексом.

Спасибо буду углублять знания
